# Angularjs: how to access to the partial or to local scope method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to handle an horizontal photo scroller thru a directive.
In the link, I'd like to measure the container in order to handle two arrow to click to make prev/next functionalities.
Th ecode is as follows:

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "scrollable": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "height": "@",
            "list": "=",
            "prefix":"@",
            "inline": "@",
            "extension": "@",
            "class": "@",
            "slide": "@"
        },
        template: 
        '<div style="position:relative">\n\
            <div id="photos{{photoid}}" class="scroller {{class}}" ng-class="[{{scrollable}}]" ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size||\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}">\n\
                <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                    ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{prefix}}{{p.file}}.thumb.{{extension||\'jpg\'}})\', width: \'{{size||\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                    ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                    <div>{{p.text||p.description}}</div>\n\
                </div>\n\
            </div>\n\
            <div class="prev" ng-if="list.length>1" nng-hide="slide<=0"             ng-click="scope.prev()"></div>\n\
            <div class="next" ng-if="list.length>1" nng-hide="slide>=list.length-1" ng-click="scope.next()"></div>\n\
        </div>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            //scope.list = JSON.parse(attrs.list);
            //.animate({scrollLeft: x}, 200);
            scope.slide = scope.slide||0;

            console.log("scope.photos: entering for id = #photos"+scope.photoid);

            var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
            var container = scroller.parent();

            console.log("scope.photos: scroller = "+scroller);
            console.log("scope.photos: container = "+container);

            var w = container.width ();
            var h = container.height(); if (h>768) h = 768; // do not exceed image maximum retina size
            console.log("scope.photos: container (w,h)=("+w+", "+h+")");
            scope.scroller  = scroller;
            scope.container = {width: w, height: h};
            scope.image     = {width: h};
            //scope.slides  = c.length;
            //scope.slide   = index;
            console.log("scope.photos: after sizing container is "+JSON.stringify(scope.container));

            // make it scrollable or not
            if (scope.list.length*h > w) {
                scroller.addClass("hScrollable");
                console.log("scope.photos: Scroller for "+scope.list.length+" added hScrollable class");
            }
            else {
                scroller.removeClass("hScrollable");
                console.log("scope.photos: Scroller for "+scope.list.length+" removed hScrollable class");
            }
            //console.log("scope.photos: Scroller for "+c.length+" photos (container w="+w+"px, image width="+h+") start scroll at index "+index+", scrolleft= "+x+" and got: "+$(scroller).scrollLeft());


            var sw = container.width();
                 w = scroller.height();     
            var x = scope.slide*w;                      // offset at the left border
            x -= (sw-w)/2;                          // center
            if (x<0)    x = 0;                      // make sure it's not underleft

            scroller.scrollLeft(x);
            //console.log("scope.photos: Scroller for "+c.length+" photos ("+w+"px width) start scroll at index "+index+", scrolleft= "+x+" and got: "+$(scroller).scrollLeft());
        },
        prev : function() {
            console.log("scope.photos: prev()");
            scope.scroller.scrollLeft(0);
        },  
        next : function() {
            console.log("scope.photos: next()");
            scope.scroller.scrollRight(0);
        }   
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, it looks like I cannot access to the width and height of the container as I get null as shown in the console as follows:

```
[Log] scope.photos: entering for id = #photosImpacReglage (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 196)
[Log] scope.photos: scroller = [object Object] (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 201)
[Log] scope.photos: container = [object Object] (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 202)
[Log] scope.photos: container (w,h)=(null, null) (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 206)
[Log] scope.photos: after sizing container is {"width":null,"height":null} (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 212)
[Log] scope.photos: Scroller for 5 removed hScrollable class (kws.corn.app.js.html, line 221)
```

Also, how can I trigger local scope prev() and next() method? I have no console message when I click despite the console.log() in the method?

---

[UPDATE 1] 
Thanks to @ClintPowell I modified the directive and it works, except the replace:true. When I comment it out, the app breaks. I don't understand.

The jsFiddle's right there: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/6mhm0tab/)

Comment: Your `next` and `prev` methods are not in the local scope. You've defined them in the directive itself. They will not be accessible. Inside your `link` function you can set `scope.next = function() {...}` etc. There is not enough context for us to tell why `scroller.parent().width()` is null. Please post a plunkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: Regarding the pre/next, you put me on the right path. Thanks. @ClintPowell

Comment: @ClintPowell I provided a fiddle. It almost works except if I set replace: true, then it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comments: your `next` and `prev` methods were not in the local scope. You defined them in the directive itself, thus they were not accessible. Inside your link function you can set `scope.next = function() {...}` etc, then they will be accessible from within your directive's scope.

The reason angular breaks when you define the `replace` attribute is that angular requires directives to have a single root element. When you define `replace`, it removes the element you attach the directive to and replaces it with your template, as defined in your directive. If you look at your jsfiddle code, your template does not have a single root element, but rather three sibling `divs`.

If you want to use `replace: true`, simply wrap all three elements in your template with a single `div`, as I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/6mhm0tab/5
Or you can simply remove the `replace` attribute and use the attached element as your root.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The fix as suggested by @ClintPowel : my functions wasn't attached to the scope.

Regarding the issue of replace:true making angularjs to generate a DOM exception, I didn't really got it. Except that Removing the englobing div in the partial make my directive working.

I'm very interested though in understanding what this error is all about, you can refer to the jsFiddle with still make the issue with the DOM.

The working code is as follows:

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "scrollable": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "height": "@",
            "list": "=",
            "prefix":"@",
            "inline": "@",
            "extension": "@",
            "class": "@",
            "slide": "="
        },
        template: 
        '<div id="photos{{photoid}}Container"\n\
            style="position:relative"\n\
            ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size||\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{height||size||\'auto\'}}\'}">\n\
            <div id="photos{{photoid}}"\n\
                class="scroller {{class}}"\n\
                ng-class="[{{scrollable}}]">\n\
                <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                    ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{prefix}}{{p.file}}.thumb.{{extension||\'jpg\'}})\', width: \'{{size||\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{height||size||\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                    ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                    <div>{{p.text||p.description}}</div>\n\
                </div>\n\
            </div>\n\
            <div class="prev" ng-if="list.length>1" ng-show="canPrev()" ng-click="prev()"></div>\n\
            <div class="next" ng-if="list.length>1" ng-show="canNext()" ng-click="next()"></div>\n\
        </div>'
        ,
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.doesScroll = function() {
                var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
                return scope.list.length*(scope.size||171)>scroller.width();
            };
            scope.canPrev = function() {
                var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
                return scroller.scrollLeft();
            };
            scope.canNext = function() {
                var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
                return scope.list.length*(scope.size||171)>scroller.scrollLeft()+scroller.width();
            };

            scope.prev = function() {
                var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
                var l = scroller.scrollLeft();
                l -= (scope.size||171);
                scroller.animate({scrollLeft:l}, 200, function(){
                    scope.$apply(scope.canPrev);
                    scope.$apply(scope.canNext);
                });
            };

            scope.next = function() {
                //console.log("scope.photos: next()");
                var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
                var l = scroller.scrollLeft();
                l += (scope.size||171);
                scroller.animate({scrollLeft:l}, 200, function(){
                    scope.$apply(scope.canPrev);
                    scope.$apply(scope.canNext);
                });
            };

            scope.slide = (scope.slide||0);
            var l = scope.slide * (scope.size||171);
            var scroller = $("#photos"+scope.photoid);
            scroller.animate({scrollLeft:l}, 200);
            //console.log("scope.photos: entering for id = #photos"+scope.photoid);
        }
    };
});
```